# What's the reason DIO and Jotaro could fly in Stardust Crusaders?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

When I watched the first season of *Jojo no Kimyou na Bouken: Stardust Crusaders*, I have never seen Jotaro fly with his stand, but suddenly in season 2 of Stardust Crusaders when Jotaro confronted DIO, he did fly. You could see on this [scene](https://youtu.be/Jh-H4Dwv5GQ?t=1m57s), they did fly when they punch each other. Is this a new ability of their stand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They aren't flying, but rather a consecutive set of "Stand leaps" combined with The World's ability to stop time. This is basically when the stand uses its power to perform a very powerful jump by either jumping or punching walls and the floor. For example, in Jotaro's fight with Dio we see him punch a wall with Star Platinum to propel him in another direction.

The instance where The World and Star Platinum attack each other and both Stand users start to "fly", it is like lots of mini Stand leaps as they propel off each other. The 2 Stands punch each other so fast they begin to rise, because the forces acting on the other are equivalent to Stand leaps.

Answer (score 0):

Time stop ➡️ Everything stops ➡️ Physics stop ➡️ Gravity stops ➡️ You can fly without gravity and Star platinum steers with the sheer power of his punches

Comment: How about when Jotaro and DIO were flying without needing Timestop?

Comment: He can fly with the sheer power of his punches.